# download the database dump to local using kubectl and pg_dump

Tags: shell, kubernetes, pg-dump

i am trying to download postgresql database dump to my local machine by using the below shell script

```
#!/bin/bash -x
namespace="staging"
current_date=`date +%d_%b_%Y`
file_name="${namespace}_${current_date}.dump"
kubectl config use-context <context_name> -n $namespace
pod_name=`kubectl get pods -n ${namespace} -l app=backend | grep backend | awk '{print $1}'`
kubectl exec -it $pod_name --container <cname> -n $namespace -- sh -c PGPASSWORD=$DATABASE_PASSWORD pg_dump --no-owner -x -Fc $DATABASE_NAME -h $DATABASE_HOST -U $DATABASE_USERNAME > $file_name
```

but this does not work and resultant file is blank without any error.

```
$DATABASE_PASSWORD, $DATABASE_NAME, $DATABASE_HOST & $DATABASE_USERNAME
```

are all environment variables.

Any help on how to get this working would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: yes they are placeholder and have the actual value on my end

Comment: Perhaps, best is to try all the 5 lines of code manually to see error

Comment: i don't see any error message when i execute it one line at a time and .dump file is blank

Comment: Did you check your variables? Run `echo $<variable>` after each command to make sure, that stored data are correct.

Comment: yes, the variables which are part of pg_dump command are only available in the container and not on the machine i am executing the shell script

Comment: I am asking about your variables: `namespace`, `current_date`, `file_name` etc. Is `pod_name` variable set correctly?

Comment: yes, they are all set correctly

Comment: If there is an error you will not see any errors in the file. This is correct behavior. Try changing the output stream to stderr and check again. This time, only the errors that have occurred will be written to the file. Without them, we will not be able to help you. Run  `kubectl exec -it $pod_name --container <cname> -n $namespace -- sh -c PGPASSWORD=$DATABASE_PASSWORD pg_dump --no-owner -x -Fc $DATABASE_NAME -h $DATABASE_HOST -U $DATABASE_USERNAME 2> error.log`  The difference is with  `2>`  operator.

Comment: the error log file is `blank` similar to database dump, there is no error but the pg_dump resultant file is blank

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak could it be some permission issue? because if i execute the pg_dump command inside the container manually the export file is generated

Comment: If this was a permission problem you should get an error. Are the files to be stored in the database dump created but empty or not existing at all?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor no, the issue still persists

Comment: If the OP can add the steps to reproduce the issue, I guess people can help better.

Comment: Could you add more details to the question? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?